# Concatenate pairs of files in a loop bash

Tags: bash, loops, concatenation, data-science, data-manipulation

I have a table that each file have the file to be concatenated

```
a.filtred.bed.gff   a.genomic.gff
b.filtred.bed.gff   b.genomic.gff
```

So, I want to concatenate in a bash loop with `for`

```
cat a.filtred.bed.gff a.genomic.gff > a.combine.gff
```

But I dont know how to do this, maybe with two varibles or matching pairs in the line, but it's not a simple logic to me

Comment: i forget to say, it's not a list. its a table, a needs to match a.filtred.bed.gff needs to match a.genomic.gff. But *a* its not the same string

Comment: What do you mean by _table_? A textfile which contains what you have posted, i.e. 2 files per line separated by spaces? How would a filename be represented which does have a space in it?

Comment: separeded by tabs

Comment: To be an acceptable question, you (1) would need to put **this** information into your question, rather than into a comment, and (2) show what attempts you did to solve the problem. Don't forget that SO is meant to **discuss** programming problems, not asking other people to simply do the job for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try a lookup.

You didn't supply the table so we can't help you load it, but if you create an associative array, you can match files in it as key/value pairs.

```
$: declare -A lookup;
$: cat file
a.filtred.bed.gff   a.genomic.gff
b.filtred.bed.gff   b.genomic.gff
$: while read k v; do lookup["$k"]="$v"; done < file
$: for k in "${!lookup[@]}"; do echo "cat $k ${lookup[$k]} > ${k}_${lookup[$k]}.merge"; done
cat b.filtred.bed.gff b.genomic.gff > b.filtred.bed.gff_b.genomic.gff.merge
cat a.filtred.bed.gff a.genomic.gff > a.filtred.bed.gff_a.genomic.gff.merge
```

Or maybe just add a third column and do it right from the table directly.

```
$: cat file
a.filtred.bed.gff a.genomic.gff myA.merge
b.filtred.bed.gff b.genomic.gff myB.merge
$: while read -r a b c; do echo "cat $a $b > $c"; done < file
cat a.filtred.bed.gff a.genomic.gff > myA.merge
cat b.filtred.bed.gff b.genomic.gff > myB.merge
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the suffixes seem constant:

```sh
for gen in *.genomic.gff; do
    prefix=${gen%.genomic.gff}
    cat "${prefix}.filtred.bed.gff" "$gen" > "${prefix}.combine.gff"
done
```